# Pulling Images from GCR into GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Today is my first day playing with GCR and GKE. So apologies if my question sounds childish.

So I have created a new registry in GCR. It is private. Using [this](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#access_token)  documentation, I got hold of my Access Token using the command

```
gcloud auth print-access-token
#<MY-ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

I know that my username is `oauth2accesstoken`

On my local laptop when I try

```
docker login https://eu.gcr.io/v2
Username: oauth2accesstoken
Password: <MY-ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

I get:

```
Login Successful
```

So now its time to create a `docker-registry` secret in Kubernetes.

I ran the below command:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry eu-gcr-io-registry --docker-server='https://eu.gcr.io/v2' --docker-username='oauth2accesstoken' --docker-password='<MY-ACCESS_TOKEN>' --docker-email='<MY_EMAIL>'
```

And then my Pod definition looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-app
    image: eu.gcr.io/<my-gcp-project>/<repo>/<my-app>:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8090
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: eu-gcr-io-registry
```

But when I spin up the pod, I get the ERROR:

```
Warning  Failed                 4m (x4 over 6m)   kubelet, node-3  Failed to pull image "eu.gcr.io/<my-gcp-project>/<repo>/<my-app>:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
```

I verified my secrets checking the YAML file and doing a `base64 --decode` on the `.dockerconfigjson` and it is correct.

So what have I missed here ?

Comment: Since you have permission issues pulling images, let me know if this [doc](https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-single-docker-repository-with-multiple-gke-projects-1672689f780c) helps.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**If your GKE cluster & GCR registry are in the same project:** You don't need to configure authentication. GKE clusters are authorized to pull from private GCR registries in the same project with no config. (Very likely you're this!)

---

**If your GKE cluster & GCR registry are in different GCP projects:** Follow these instructions to give "service account" of your GKE cluster access to read private images in your GCR cluster: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#granting_users_and_other_projects_access_to_a_registry

In a nutshell, this can be done by:

```
gsutil iam ch  serviceAccount:[PROJECT_NUMBER]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com:objectViewer gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

where `[BUCKET_NAME]` is the GCS bucket storing your GCR images (like `artifacts.[PROJECT-ID].appspot.com`) and `[PROJECT_NUMBER]` is the **numeric** GCP project ID hosting your GKE cluster.

Comment: My GKE & GCR image is in the same project, however without providing additional credentials I am getting this:
`Failed to pull image "eu.gcr.io/project/we...": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request...`
It doesn't look like that same project gives any guarantee.
EDIT: Well actually found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54043495/gke-cluster-cant-pull-errimagepull-from-gcr-registry-in-same-project-gitlab

Comment: Yeah your cluster’s identity and scopes should allow access to the Cloud Storage API for GCR access. By default, GKE clusters have this if you’re creating without —service-account or —scopes customization.

Comment: your nodes need to have the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only` oauth scope.

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue there should be insufficient permissions on your service account, check permissions related to kubernetes cluster, cloud storage etc and it should definitely work without any special credentials.